# Are there any secret commands?

Tags: exapunks

One thing I hated about Shenzhen I/O was that there were secret commands that you don't learn until later in the game.  I spent a significant time trying to optimize puzzles that required those commands to optimize.

Are there any secret commands in EXAPUNKS that aren't explained in the first magazine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort of.

There aren't any EXA commands, but there are 'macros', which are the EXAPUNKS equivalent to a [preprocessor directive](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/24295/preprocessor-directive). All these macros do is allow you to replace repetitive code with shorthand, and because that shorthand is converted to code before the code is run, it doesn't add any utility in terms of optimizing code.

Instead of writing:

```
COPY F M
COPY F M
COPY F M
COPY F M
```

...you can write:

```
@REP 4 <--The number of times to repeat the command
COPY F M
@END
```

...and instead of writing:

```
COPY 0 F
COPY 1 F
COPY 2 F
COPY 3 F
COPY 4 F
```

...you can write:

```
@REP 5
COPY @{0,1} F <-- start at 0, increase by 1 each time
@END
```

The arguments passed to the macro functions *must be numbers*. Because the macros are run before the program begins running you can not use registers in macros.

So, yes and no. Yes, there are new and helpful commands in the second magazine, but no, these secret commands do not allow you new functionality that you didn't have before unlocking it, and will not cause you to have to re-optimize your bots.

Comment: Ah. For anyone interested in reading it from the magazine, it's in `Steam/SteamApps/common/EXAPUNKS/Content/manual/digital_en_2.pdf` on page 28